# Correct answer includes a new question

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

Talking specifically about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42070864/5675325).

The only thing I've done was to write a comment explaining what was done is not a good thing, but the answer is still having both an answer and question (understandable, the comment was added recently).

Didn't want to edit the answer and remove the content having to do with the question because the user might not know how to get it afterwards, but that might be the best approach if i include a comment with reference explaining how the user can reach that content (if wants to).

How shall we proceed?

Comment: Remove the question parts - but make sure you don't remove anything related to the answer, and drop a link in the comments to the revision history and explain how OP can retrieve the text

Comment: Thank you @Zoe the transgirl, just did that. If you write that comment as answer i mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly like Zoe the transgirl told me to

> Remove the question parts - but make sure you don't remove anything
>   related to the answer, and drop a link in the comments to the revision
>   history and explain how OP can retrieve the text

You can see what was done in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42070864/revisions).